# How to parse a RFC3339 in Go?

Tags: go

My date looks like this

```
2019-03-29T09:32:52Z
```

Please help me parse it using Go's standard time package

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just had the wrong layout

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, "2019-03-29T09:32:52Z")
    fmt.Println(t, err)
}
```

Comment: [Go predefines common formats](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants), such as time.RFC3339.